# Inflate a View on Menu Selection

Tags: android, android-view

I have my main view showing just fine.

My trouble is when the user selects the menu button and then the user preferences icon I would like one of my views to be inflated and visible. This view of course has options on it that I want to display for the user to choose from.

The difficulty I am having is getting a handle on my view to set the visibility. I "believe" this to be because the view isn't inflated yet but I am not sure the best way to get it inflated.

Further should I do it as part of the OnCreate steps then hide it or inflate only when needed. Either way how do I inflate a view?

TIA
JB

I'm sorry I have done a poor job with this question. Here is some code:

I have a relativelayout called userpreferences. When the user selects the menu then the preferences button I want to show that view so they can modify their settings.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{ 

    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    { 
        case R.id.menu_save:
    ..... code .....
        case R.id.menu_Preferences: 
            //Inflate view here so user can select options
            return true;
```

Comment: no "enter" key on your keyboard? Your question is really hard to read...

Comment: Sorry I've been up all night trying to get this done by new year.

Comment: so you want to show a view(inflate it from xml first)  when the user hits the MENU key? Perhaps you would like to elaborate on you question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, way much readable ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: question changed.

You're best way to handle this is probably just start a new activity.

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, NewActvity.class));
```

Will do the trick.

---

You're question is quite vague... anyhow..

In a normal activity, your activity will already know what view you are talking about by setting 'setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);'  in OnCreate.

From that point on you can inflate any view by simply doing per example:

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
```

If you're building a slightly more complicated set-up you might still need to inflate the root view first. You can do that with per example:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, null);
```

From that point on you can use the example again, but instead you'd make it:

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
```

For the rest of your question: When to do this is up to what you wanna do exactly, but generally inflating them in the onCreate will do fine.

Once you 'have' your view, you can set its visibility with mTextView.setVisibility();
It will take either View.GONE, View.INVISIBLE or View.VISIBLE which are static values so you won't have to initiate any objects to reach them.

Comment: This did the trick. Don't forget to add your new activity to the manifest like I did at first. Thank You!